# get moving speed from accelormeter android

Tags: android, performance

I need to get the moving speed from the accelerometer.

I've managed to get the acceleration from each axis

I need to detect sudden movements like someone falling so GPS won't work

Comment: sudden movements are what the accelerometer is for, high forces.

Comment: well I need to detect if someone falls down, would you be able to recommend anything?

Comment: If someone falls down probably you will notice a dramatic change in the z-axe. However if the mobile gets smashed probably it would be more according to listen if the power is still on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html
 and this one http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Since Velocity is defined as the integral of acceleration (vice versa acceleration is the derivative of velocity), simply [integrate the accelerometer output to find the velocity](http://blog.prosig.com/2007/10/05/calculating-velocity-or-displacement-from-acceleration-time-histories/). Integration can be performed twice to calculate the displacement (position).

Alternatively, if all you need to know is whether the phone is (or has recently) moved and not how accurately then you could try this method. You could apply a low-pass filter such as a Moving Average to the absolute accelerometer output to get measure of recent movement.

Note that integration has an inherent problem with accelerometers and that is that the output is going to drift (accumulate error) over time. Likewise low-pass filtering is going to introduce lag.

Best regards,